# How to set PUNICODE_STRING without RtlInitUnicodeString?

Tags: c++

I tried to write an injector but using LdrLoadDll instead of LoadLibrary.
However, I am unable to assign PUNICODE_STRING. the compiler shows `Error C2326 'main :: _ params :: _ params (void)': function cannot access 'dllName'` But why

If you replace LdrLoadDll and its definition with Beep (kernel32.dll) and, the "params" structure, then everything works and the sound appears

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ntdll.lib")
using namespace std;
EXTERN_C NTSYSAPI NTSTATUS NTAPI NtCreateThreadEx(PHANDLE,
    ACCESS_MASK, LPVOID, HANDLE, LPVOID, LPVOID,
    BOOL, SIZE_T, SIZE_T, SIZE_T, LPVOID);
typedef HMODULE(__stdcall* _LdrLoadDll)(
    wchar_t* PathToFile,
    unsigned long Flags,
    PUNICODE_STRING ModuleFileName,
    PHANDLE* ModuleHandle
    );


int main()
{
    DWORD targetProcId =212;

    HANDLE targetOpened = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, targetProcId);
 
    _LdrLoadDll LdrLoadDll = (_LdrLoadDll)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll"), "LdrLoadDll");

    UNICODE_STRING dllName;
    dllName.Buffer = (wchar_t*)L"DllTest32.dll";
    dllName.Length = wcslen(dllName.Buffer) * sizeof(wchar_t);
    dllName.MaximumLength = dllName.Length + sizeof(wchar_t);

    static struct _params {
        wchar_t* PathToFile = (wchar_t*)L"C:\\DllTest32.dll";
        unsigned long Flags = 0;
        PUNICODE_STRING ModuleFileName = &dllName; //something wrong here — Error C2326 'main::_params::_params(void)': function cannot access 'dllName'
        PHANDLE* ModuleHandle = 0;
    } params;

    HANDLE rt;
    NtCreateThreadEx(
        &rt, PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD, NULL, targetOpened,
        LdrLoadDll,
        &params,
        FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A local class cannot access non-static variables of the enclosing function.

To fix, you need to access `dllName` outside of the class:

```
static struct _params {
    wchar_t* PathToFile = (wchar_t*)L"C:\\DllTest32.dll";
    unsigned long Flags = 0;
    PUNICODE_STRING ModuleFileName;
    PHANDLE* ModuleHandle = 0;
} params;
params.ModuleFileName = &dllName;
```